# What is an elegant 'ruby' way (within rails if it matters) to alter a loop's function every Nth iteration while using list.each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

What is an elegant 'ruby' way to alter a loop's function every Nth iteration?  I would prefer not to use `(1..50).each do |i|` because I want to iterate over every object in a list `objects`.

```
  objects.each do |object|
   #Do this with object information
   #Do not do this if this is the third time through the loop
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
objects.each_with_index do |object, idx|
   if idx == 2 # third time

   # or
   # if idx % 3 == 2 # every third time

     # do special thing
   else
     # do normal thing
   end
end
```

Comment: Did not know I could  _with_index. Awesome.

Comment: There is several (and very useful methods `each_with_XXX` (with object, with index, each_slice, etc) @Ecnalyr .